# 'DatasetReader' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, dictionary, rasterio

**how can i iterate over image pixels by pixels readed by rasterio?**

```py
img = rasterio.open("FalseColorImages.jpg", masked=True)
profile = img.profile
```

**i try this but it took me to error**

```py
for i in np.nditer(img.shape[0]):
    for j in np.nditer(img.shape[1]):
                    print(img[i][j])
```

**and i try this also**

```py
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
          for j in range(img.shape[1]):
                    print(img[i][j])
```

**and i try this also**

```py
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
          for j in range(img.shape[1]):
                    print(list(img[i][j]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was just open an image with rasterio. Now you need to read this image by using

```
img.read(channel_number_to_read)
```

in this way, you will have a matrix that represents the image channel. So you can iterate over it.

Note: an image can have different channels. You can check how many channels it has by looking at *count* in the output of the code below:

```
image.profile
```

Comment: can you give example to more understand for img.read(channel_number_to_read)   Is it possible to be like this  img.read(3)   ?

Comment: Yes. The example you wrote is right. Be aware the bands/channels you want to use, for example, if your image comes from Sentinel2 or Landsat, 2, 3 and 4 bands refer to blue, green, and red, respectively.

Comment: so i will concatenate the red +green +blue channel to get image original and iterate over it?@GabrielTrindade

Comment: You can read all three all once, giving a list to .read:

img.read([red_band, green_band, blue_band])